# Uniqueness of LASSO solution in maximum likelihood problems

Tags: self-study, lasso

I need more information about uniqueness of LASSO solution when using $\ell_1$ penalization with likelihood functions.

I read on many sources that this solution is unique given that the columns of $X$ are in general position, so that it is sufficient for the predictors to be continuous variables. Anyway, I guess this is only valid with linear regression.

Is it the same when penalizing likelihood functions?

I have doubts because I just tried to fit a LASSO Logit model on more than 60'000 dummy variables and 11'000 units in R with glmnet package and nothing went wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by unique and why dummies are a problem? I don't think LASSO will usually pick the same subset of X on different folds of the data, but perhaps you mean something else entirely.

Comment: does this paper help? http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/lassounique.pdf it's about the column space more than the particular encoding you use

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I mean something different, I'm not referring to unique subsets of X. With unique I mean there is only only solution value per each coefficient.

Comment: @Chaconne My doubts arise from that paper. The author writes in the abstract that "the case of non-uniqueness in lasso
solutions [...] only arises when some of the
predictor variables are discrete", and later in the paper, after Lemma 3: "the definition of general position [...] is naturally
satisfied when the entries of the predictor matrix X are drawn from a continuous probability
distribution". But in my example the predictors are clearly discrete variables {0,1}.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I was talking about a LASSO logit model, I edited my question adding this information.

Comment: results in section 2.3 of the paper linked by Chaconne specialize to $\ell_1$ penalized logistic regression (but still with continuous features)

Answer (score 2):

The uniqueness of the lasso solution, as far as I know, is guaranteed since the objective equation:

$$\|\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta\|^2_2 + \lambda\|\beta\|_1$$

Is convex in $\beta$.  I suppose the can be an edge case where $\mathbf{X}$ is rank deficient, so you just need to be careful with your indicators.

There is a different problem when using indicators in the lasso, though.  If you have coefficients regularized out of your model, shouldn't that mean that variable didn't matter?  But you have other levels of that factor variable that are still in your model.  In these cases I prefer to use the grouped lasso method, but I guess it's not totally necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I was talking about a LASSO logit model, I edited my question adding this information.

Comment: the answer given by tim is wrong. while it follows that a solution always exists, the only further thing you could derive from the the objective function is that the set of solutions is convex. you would need strict convexity of the objective (i.e. $n<p$, $rank(X)=p$.) in order to ensure uniqueness of the solution.  of course each different solution would yield the same prediction. glm calculates you only one solution path. there might be more: see the link from chaconne for prob. statements about uniquenes of the solution. in your case lemma 5 in this paper looks promising.

Comment: @BloXX wrote "of course each different solution would yield the same prediction". How do you conclude that? Each solution will have the same objective value, but unless there is something else going on, will not necessarily yield the same predictions.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone in section 2.1 of the paper cited by Chaconne it is said that any solution will lead to the same fitted value $X\hat{\beta}$